# Why can't the DVD format store FHD 1080p or 720P (given the fact that their storage capacity is more than 4 GB)?

Tags: video, resolution, dvd, blu-ray, 1080p

A standard 1080p movie is **4 GB** or less with h.264 or h.265. And the size that a dvd format can support is **4.7 Gb**.Which means DVD format should store1080p movies. So why do people say that bluray format is used for 1080p and dvd for 480p (since it can't support 1080p).

Comment: If there's something wrong with the question, any suggestion how to improve it?

Comment: You are asking 2 completely different questions. That is not how we do things on this site. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: well that was a leading question from the actual question that I asked. Nevertheless I will separate the later. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DVDs *can* store 1080p h.264 videos, you just burn the file to it and view it on any computer or device that supports it.

The [DVD Video standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video) though was made in a time before h.264 and 1080 video was common or even conceived of. Thus the standard format of video that must be supported for a player to be called a "DVD" player is upto 720p video encoded in H.262/MPEG-2.

Many later generation DVD players were able to play DivX or Xvid video but this is not a standard feature or format for DVD Video. The only video disc that can be **guaranteed** to work in a **DVD player** is one that is formatted in the standard DVD Video format.

I suspect that Blu-ray in it's true [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray#Media_format) may not quite fit a full film onto a DVD, but the newer standards might, and they'd require a newer Blu-Ray player to suit.  I don't know *if* you can have a DVD with the Blu-Ray filesystem and video on it and it be playable as my Google fu is failing today, but it seems kind of pointless when a Blu-ray writer is pretty cheap these days.